# Yarn/Webpack build error TS1005: '=' expected

Tags: typescript, webpack, jhipster, eslint, yarnpkg

I have a project generated with JHipster generator (...for those who know it).

When I run the command `gradlew bootrun -Pprod`, during the building chain I have this error:
**ERROR in node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(159,60): error TS1005: '=' expected.**

```
> Task :yarn_install
yarn install v1.22.10
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@0.5.x"
warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.3"
warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.7.3"
warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.3"
warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.7"
warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@~0.5.1"
warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.4.2"
warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.3"
warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@~0.5.0"
warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.3"
warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.1"
warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@~0.2.0"
warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.1.41"
warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.4.2"
success Already up-to-date.
$ node node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/install.js
Found PhantomJS at C:\Users\user\Desktop\workspace\myproject\node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt\lib\phantom\bin\phantomjs.exe ...verifying
PhantomJS is previously installed at C:\Users\user\Desktop\workspace\myproject\node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt\lib\phantom\bin\phantomjs.exe
Done in 1.40s.

> Task :webpack
yarn run v1.22.10
$ yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:prod:main && yarn run clean-www
$ rimraf build/{aot,www}
$ yarn run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile
warning From Yarn 1.0 onwards, scripts don't require "--" for options to be forwarded. In a future version, any explicit "--" will be forwarded as-is to the scripts.
$ node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile
MergetJsonsWebpackPlugin compilation started...
MergetJsonsWebpackPlugin compilation completed...
MergetJsonsWebpackPlugin emit starts...
MergetJsonsWebpackPlugin emit completed...
Hash: 88cf9e1b49032ec44a81
Version: webpack 3.10.0
Time: 7728ms
                                                Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
                        swagger-ui/dist/lib/marked.js    15.7 kB          [emitted]
         content/e0e4133ddd3bd332e5cd6a0616b5c123.png     227 kB          [emitted]
            app/global.88cf9e1b49032ec44a81.bundle.js   41 bytes       0  [emitted]         global
         app/polyfills.88cf9e1b49032ec44a81.bundle.js   40 bytes       1  [emitted]         polyfills
              app/main.88cf9e1b49032ec44a81.bundle.js   42 bytes       2  [emitted]         main
          app/manifest.88cf9e1b49032ec44a81.bundle.js    1.39 kB       3  [emitted]         manifest
                 global-sass.88cf9e1b49032ec44a81.css    3.98 kB       0  [emitted]         global
                        swagger-ui/dist/css/reset.css  773 bytes          [emitted]
                        swagger-ui/dist/css/style.css    3.49 kB          [emitted]
                   swagger-ui/dist/css/typography.css    0 bytes          [emitted]
                       swagger-ui/dist/css/screen.css    43.6 kB          [emitted]
                        swagger-ui/dist/css/print.css    41.7 kB          [emitted]
 swagger-ui/dist/lib/highlight.9.1.0.pack_extended.js  310 bytes          [emitted]
            swagger-ui/dist/lib/jquery.slideto.min.js  365 bytes          [emitted]
             swagger-ui/dist/lib/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js    3.52 kB          [emitted]
             swagger-ui/dist/lib/jquery.wiggle.min.js  536 bytes          [emitted]
       swagger-ui/dist/lib/object-assign-pollyfill.js  349 bytes          [emitted]
                 swagger-ui/dist/lib/swagger-oauth.js    7.04 kB          [emitted]
          swagger-ui/dist/lib/highlight.9.1.0.pack.js      11 kB          [emitted]
         content/eb90ee6f9923366bbb893340fdf1afa5.jpg     537 kB          [emitted]  [big]
                  swagger-ui/dist/lib/backbone-min.js    19.4 kB          [emitted]
                      swagger-ui/dist/lib/es5-shim.js    22.7 kB          [emitted]
                   swagger-ui/dist/lib/js-yaml.min.js    43.5 kB          [emitted]
                    swagger-ui/dist/lib/lodash.min.js    51.9 kB          [emitted]
              swagger-ui/dist/lib/handlebars-4.0.5.js    71.5 kB          [emitted]
              swagger-ui/dist/lib/jquery-1.8.0.min.js      92 kB          [emitted]
                swagger-ui/dist/lib/jsoneditor.min.js     130 kB          [emitted]
             swagger-ui/dist/lib/sanitize-html.min.js     130 kB          [emitted]
                    swagger-ui/dist/swagger-ui.min.js     453 kB          [emitted]  [big]
                                swagger-ui/index.html    7.95 kB          [emitted]
                                          favicon.ico    5.03 kB          [emitted]
                                      manifest.webapp  778 bytes          [emitted]
                                           robots.txt  250 bytes          [emitted]
                                       ./i18n/en.json    20.4 kB          [emitted]
                                           index.html    1.24 kB          [emitted]
                                       ./i18n/it.json    21.8 kB          [emitted]
precache-manifest.49cc7d4d8ebb53758eb200355381d690.js    3.55 kB          [emitted]
                                    service-worker.js  955 bytes          [emitted]
   [0] ./src/main/webapp/app/polyfills.ts 0 bytes {1} [built]
        factory:4224ms building:2739ms = 6963ms
   [1] ./src/main/webapp/content/scss/global.scss 41 bytes {0} [built]
        factory:4224ms building:25ms = 4249ms
   [2] ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts 0 bytes {2} [built]
        factory:4224ms building:2741ms = 6965ms
   [3] ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/main/webapp/content/scss/global.scss 4.16 kB [built]
       [] -> factory:16ms building:1429ms = 1445ms
    + 3 hidden modules

ERROR in node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(159,60): error TS1005: '=' expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(169,64): error TS1005: '=' expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(186,46): error TS1005: '=' expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(195,44): error TS1005: '=' expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(300,60): error TS1005: '=' expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(310,64): error TS1005: '=' expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(327,46): error TS1005: '=' expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(336,44): error TS1005: '=' expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(435,45): error TS1005: '=' expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(444,49): error TS1005: '=' expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(457,31): error TS1005: '=' expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(466,29): error TS1005: '=' expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(493,46): error TS1005: '=' expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-scale/index.d.ts(38,68): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-scale/index.d.ts(2288,19): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-scale/index.d.ts(2288,27): error TS1131: Property or signature expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-scale/index.d.ts(2289,9): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-scale/index.d.ts(2290,9): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-scale/index.d.ts(2290,50): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-scale/index.d.ts(2295,11): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-scale/index.d.ts(2296,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

MergetJsonsWebpackPlugin emit starts...
MergetJsonsWebpackPlugin emit completed...
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':webpack'.
> Process 'command 'yarn.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
5 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

I tried to change some versions of typescript or @types/d3 but nothing changed.

Is it possibile to configure eslint in order to exclude something?

Thanks

Comment: @GaëlMarziou it happens only when building a prod build. With the dev profile, or yarn start, all it's okay. The project is made with JHipster 4.14

Comment: I don't know. I taked on hand this project now. The command mentioned by you is not working:yarn run v1.22.10
error Command "webapp:prod" not found.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou this is the script in my file package.json: "webpack:prod": "yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:prod:main && yarn run clean-www"

Comment: @GaëlMarziou tried now. I've always the same problem "`ERROR in node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(159,60): error TS1005: '=' expected.`"

Comment: Gradle node plugin install its own version of node and npm (see gradle.properties)  so now we know that this not a bug that depends on environment.

Comment: Now you have 2 possible ways: 1. you try to upgrade different parts of your dev dependencies (typescript, etc, ..)  to make your build pass or 2. use `git bisect`to find which commit introduced the bug. If you are lucky, #1 could be a quick win but could also drives you into more problems. #2 will compensate somehow for the lack of continuous integration for years and help you to identify which library or change you should review

Comment: @GaëlMarziou My `gradle.properties` file contains 
`# Build properties
node_version=8.9.4
npm_version=5.6.0
yarn_version=1.3.2`

I have a dedicated remote machine where this application runs (in this machine there is only this web application).

Could be a solution to install in this machine, these node and npm versions ?

Comment: Application runs on this machine but is it able to compile it? I would not call it a solution, only a short term workaround. For mid term your project must be fixed. Try to find what's different between these machines